# Disable CSS transitions on page load only

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I have a div styled to have smooth transitions on background-color when hovered. This div is displayed in many pages (including homepage) but in homepage it has a different background-color.

```
div {
    border:1px solid;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:    0.5s;
    -o-transition:      0.5s;
    transition:         0.5s;
}

div.homepage {
    background-color:#777;
}

div:hover, div.homepage:hover {
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

Since this div is included with a PHP snippet on each page, the idea (to keep code clean) is to output a generic div with PHP and then add a "homepage" class on homepage only, via jQuery.

```
$('div').addClass("homepage");
```

Unfortunately, this causes an undesired transition on page load (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWQHK/3/), for sake of clarity click "Run" after loading). How can I disable CSS transitions on page load only, without affecting normal behaviour (when div is hovered)?

Answer (score 19):

This is what worked for me:
http://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/

Essentially, you add a class to the body tag:

```
<body class="preload">
```

Which disables the transitions:

```
.preload * {
 -webkit-transition: none !important;
 -moz-transition: none !important;
 -ms-transition: none !important;
 -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

Then once the page has loaded you remove the class:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("preload");
});
```

Simples! :D

Comment: As also on CSSTricks the code has `$("window").load()` this does not work, you need to put `$(window).load()`.  Removing the quotes from window.

Comment: It's extremely useful for me. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This didn't work for me with links that are styled as buttons, but .preload * { transition: none !important; } in conjunction with the on load jQuery body preload class removal did, note that $(window).load(function() { should also be $( window ).on('load', function() { in more recent jQuery versions.

Answer (score 1):

Disable transitions on page load only:

```
<body class="js-stop-transition">
...
<script>document.body.classList.remove('js-stop-transition')</script>
</body>
```

And add to CSS:

```
body.js-stop-transition * { transition:none !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The transition is forced when you dynamically add the class `homepage` to the `div`.

If the `div` is loaded with the `class` there is not any transition in load.

In your html:

```
<div class="homepage"></div>
```

Add the class in PHP before send it to client side.

Comment: That was my second choise, but since my goal is to keep code clean, the idea was to output a unique code in PHP, simply writing `<div></div>` and then add the jquery snippet on homepage only.

Comment: Other option may be to enable css transitions in javascript after you establish dinamic classes to div elements.

Comment: The problem with that is that changes in an event function are applied at the end of its execution. You must apply `addClass` next with a timer for example (so lets `onLoad` event ends) add css transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Would'n it be ok if you simply set the initial gray color for the div instead of white ?
Like this :

```
div {
    border:1px solid;
    background-color:#777;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
   -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
   -moz-transition:    0.5s;
   -o-transition:      0.5s;
    transition:         0.5s;   
}
```

See updated fiddle here : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWQHK/5/)

Comment: Unfortunately not, since only homepage should have grey color.

Answer (score 0):

My window load too fast, so only this works for me:

CSS

```
body {
  --transition: 0s; 
}
div {
  /* ... */
  transition: var(--transition); 
}
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.body.style.setProperty("--transition", "2s");
});
```

In this case if you have many different transitions it could be a get difficult

Answer (score -3):

Initially write only following properties

```
       div {
     border:1px solid;
     background-color:#fff;
     display:inline-block;
     width:100%;
     height:100px;
 }

 div.homepage {
     background-color:#777;
 }

 div:hover, div.homepage:hover {
     background-color:#f00;
 }
```

after adding your homepage class, append remaining properties like this

```
      var transProperty=$('<style>div {  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;   -moz-transition: 0.5s;   -o-transition:  0.5s;     transition:  0.5s; }</style>');
      $('head').append(transProperty);
```